# How do I cast an UInt32 to a (negative) Int32 in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, int32, uint32

I have the following number of type `System.UInt32`: 4.294.967.176 (in bytes: `FFFF FF88`).

I have to interpret this number as a number of type `System.Int32`, where it will be: -120 (in bytes still: `FFFF FF88`).

In languages like C or C++ a simple type cast would solve my problem, but type casting in PowerShell:

```bsh
[Int32][UInt32]4294967176
```

throws an error:

```
Cannot convert value "4294967176" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an
Int32."
At line:1 char:1
+ [Int32][UInt32]4294967176
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastIConvertible
```

It looks like PowerShell is trying to "convert" the value instead of just casting it. So, how do I cast `System.UInt32` to `System.Int32`, meaning not changing the data, but using another interpretation/representation?

Comment: 4294967178 is actually 0xFFFFFF8A or -118 when interpreted in two's complement. Without compiling actual C#, one way of doing it (which literally reinterprets the data) is `[BitConverter]::ToInt32([BitConverter]::GetBytes([uint32] 4294967178))`. There may be a shorter way by exploiting some method somewhere that I don't know about; on the runtime level this cast is a single instruction, but I don't think there's a direct code path for it in PowerShell.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The last digit was a typo, I corrected it. Your solution works, when adding 0 as the second parameter of ToInt32 (as start index). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since .Net numeric data types support conversion into hex equivalents, convert the UInt32 into string first. Then use `System.Convert.ToInt32()` and parse hex to int. Like so,

```
$u = [UInt32]4294967176
$u.tostring('x')
ffffff88

# Convert hex based value to int
$i =  [convert]::toint32($u.tostring('x'), 16) 

# Check that type is int32
$i.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                             BaseType
-------- -------- ----                             --------
True     True     Int32                            System.ValueType

# Value    
$i
-120
```

Comment: The solution from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63464374/how-to-cast-an-uint32-to-a-negative-int32-in-powershell?noredirect=1#comment112224714_63464374) is slightly faster, but not that much that it would matter imo. Code for comparison: `$u = [System.UInt32] 4294967176; (Measure-Command {1..100000 | % {[System.Convert]::ToInt32($u.ToString('x'), 16)}}).Ticks; (Measure-Command {1..100000 | % {[System.BitConverter]::ToInt32([System.BitConverter]::GetBytes($u), 0)}}).Ticks`

Answer (score 0):

No need for any string-operations. Just use the bitconverter-functions:

```
$u   = [UInt32]4294967176
$arr = [bitconverter]::GetBytes($u)
[bitconverter]::ToInt32($arr,0)
```

Or if you prefer a simple memory copy then go with this approach (its not only more code but is also slower than option 1 wich I did not expect):

```
$u = [UInt32]4294967176
$m = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]
$pu = $m::AllocHGlobal($m::SizeOf($u))
$m::WriteIntPtr($pu, $u)
$i = $m::ReadInt32($pu)
$m::FreeHGlobal($pu)
write-host $i
```

You could also go with a direct convertion via embededd C# code if you need it as fast as possible. Here a sample for that:

```
Add-Type 'public class Converter{public static int ToInt(uint u){return(int)u;}}'
$u = [UInt32]4294967176
$i = [Converter]::ToInt($u)
Write-Host $i
```